# Reporting Services - how to email a report without a fixed schedule

Tags: winforms, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I'm planning a winform which will let the user preview a report (generated with Reporting Services) and then the user can send the report to certain persons by clicking a button in the form.

I know that reports can be distributed via email using subscriptions, but the problem is that a subscription requires a fixed schedule (once a week/month, etc.), and in my case the report should be sent anytime the user clicks the button - there is no defined schedule.

Is it possible to define a subscription for a report without a schedule?
What is the best way to send a report via email on demand of the user?

Thanks.

(I'm using Sql Server 2008, Visual Studio 2008.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way:

- Call the [ReportServer web service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169926.aspx) to fetch the report into your app.
- Send it from your app

Unrelated: the [ReportViewer Control](http://www.gotreportviewer.com/) may be more useful in your app

Comment: +1: you can get the report as a stream, and then attach it as a file from memory. No need to create a on-disk file.